# flutter web load css and images

Tags: html, css, flutter-web

I have this in my index.html

```
<img src="img/splash.png" class="center"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
```

The styles and img folders are both in the 'web' folder.
The splash.png file is found, but for the css file I get this:

`The stylesheet https://myapp-24b9f.web.app/forms/styles/styles.css was not loaded...`.
The url I'm loading is: `https://myapp-24b9f.web.app/forms/somepage`

Why is the image searched relatively to the 'web' folder, and the css file relatively to 'forms'?

Answer (score 0):

I moved this to be the first line in the  and it solved it:

```
    <base href="/">
```